# C# Class structure for WCF DataContract

Tags: c#, wcf

How would I implement the following as a C# Class structure that will be used in a WCF service?
This structure is in a document from which this class will be created. It's mainly the person class which can have multiple occurances which I'm having the problem with.

Item - Class

identifier - Class (member of Item)

- field1 (int)
- field2 (string)

details - Class (member of Item)

- detail1 (int)
- detail2 (string)
- ...

persons - Class (member of Item)

person - Class (can have 1 to 200 occurances)

- info2 (string)

I have the following so far and am not sure what I need to do to complete:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    public class identifier
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int field1;

        [DataMember]
        public string field2;
    }

    public class details
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int detail1;

        [DataMember]
        public string detail2;
    }

    public class persons
    {
        public class person
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why only put `[DataContract]` on only one of the classes?

Comment: @JeremyK - I haven't got round to that yet. I'm just trying to piece this together. It's also my first WCF service.

Comment: This is an entity modelling question, not a WCF question. Also, nested classes are unconventional.

Comment: You can use a `List<person>` if you want to include multiple instances of `person`.

Comment: @hugh that, and I always though you should capitalize the first letter for class names... :P

Comment: I always capitalize the first letter of class names, this was straight from the documentation. They are actually using camel casing for class names!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By nesting a *declaration* of a class within another class there's no *instance* of it created, somehow magically. Declaring data for a WCF contract isn't anyhow different—except the respective attribute decorations—from declaring any other data structures. Hence you are probably looking for something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Identifier { … }

[DataContract]
public class Details { … }

[DataContract]
public class Person { … }

[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public Identifier ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Details Details { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```